# PSTricks plots wrong

Tags: pstricks, plot, pst-plot

I want to plot a parabola and use therefore the following code:

```
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-math}
%...
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3.5)(6,3)
     \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt,subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=black!20]
     \psaxes(0,0)(-2,-3.5)(6,3)
     \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt}
     \psplot[linecolor=red]{-1}{5}{-0.5(x-2)^2+2}
\end{pspicture}
```

But I get this wrong function plotted. I can't find my mistake. What is wrong?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a multiplication symbol; you need:

```
\psplot[linecolor=red]{-1}{5}{-0.5*(x-2)^2+2}
%                                 ^
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very simple solution but it worked :)